# cannot push project to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, db2

I have an application written in node.js which i am trying to upload to heroku. I am using DB2 as well. I used the following commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "pushing 7th try"
git push heroku master
```

and it is coming back with this beautiful (NOT) chunk of errors:

```
remote:        Rebuild Process: Found clidriver at -> /tmp/build_ca1696e7/node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver
remote:        
remote:        Downloading of clidriver skipped - build is in progress...
remote:        
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_ca1696e7/node_modules/ibm_db/build'
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings/src/odbc.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings/src/odbc_connection.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings/src/odbc_statement.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings/src/odbc_result.o
remote:          SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings.node
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_ca1696e7/node_modules/ibm_db/build'
remote:        
remote:        Error: Command failed: node-gyp configure build  --IS_DOWNLOADED=true --IBM_DB_HOME="$IBM_DB_HOME"
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBC::UV_AfterCreateConnection(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:216:27: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          216 |     data->cb->Call(1, info);
remote:              |                           ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc.cpp:29:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:228:27: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          228 |     data->cb->Call(2, info);
remote:              |                           ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc.cpp:29:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Value> ODBC::CallbackSQLError(SQLSMALLINT, SQLHANDLE, char*, Nan::Callback*)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:1413:19: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:         1413 |   cb->Call(1, info);
remote:              |                   ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc.cpp:29:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.cpp:24:
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp: At global scope:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/node.h:787:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
remote:          787 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
remote:              |                                           ^
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/node.h:821:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
remote:          821 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
remote:              |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:1577:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
remote:         1577 | NODE_MODULE(odbc_bindings, init)
remote:              | ^~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.cpp:23:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = node::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:85:78:   required from here
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h:10886:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
remote:        10886 |                reinterpret_cast<Callback>(callback), type);
remote:              |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = Nan::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
remote:        ../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:65:61:   required from here
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h:10886:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Value> ODBC::GetColumnValue(SQLHSTMT, Column, uint16_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:592:9: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
remote:          592 |         if((int) column.type == SQL_DBCLOB)
remote:              |         ^~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:598:5: note: here
remote:          598 |     case SQL_BLOB :
remote:              |     ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:599:9: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
remote:          599 |         if((int) column.type == SQL_BLOB)
remote:              |         ^~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:605:5: note: here
remote:          605 |     default :
remote:              |     ^~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Value> ODBC::GetOutputParameter(Parameter)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:734:9: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
remote:          734 |         if((int) prm.type == SQL_NUMERIC)
remote:              |         ^~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:736:5: note: here
remote:          736 |     case SQL_BIGINT :
remote:              |     ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:780:9: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
remote:          780 |         if((int) prm.type == SQL_DECIMAL)
remote:              |         ^~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:782:5: note: here
remote:          782 |     case SQL_FLOAT :
remote:              |     ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:825:9: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
remote:          825 |         if((int) prm.type == SQL_DBCLOB)
remote:              |         ^~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:829:5: note: here
remote:          829 |     case SQL_BLOB :
remote:              |     ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:830:9: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
remote:          830 |         if((int) prm.type == SQL_BLOB)
remote:              |         ^~
remote:        ../src/odbc.cpp:834:5: note: here
remote:          834 |     default :
remote:              |     ^~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCConnection::UV_AfterOpen(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:310:35: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          310 |   data->cb->Call(err ? 1 : 0, argv);
remote:              |                                   ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:25:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCConnection::UV_AfterClose(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:534:35: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          534 |   data->cb->Call(err ? 1 : 0, argv);
remote:              |                                   ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:25:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCConnection::UV_AfterCreateStatement(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:909:26: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          909 |   data->cb->Call( 2, info);
remote:              |                          ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:25:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCConnection::UV_Query(uv_work_t*)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:1094:51: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
remote:         1094 |                                 (SQLPOINTER)data->arraySize, 0);
remote:              |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCConnection::UV_AfterQuery(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:1148:27: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:         1148 |     data->cb->Call(2, info);
remote:              |                           ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:25:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:1178:27: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:         1178 |     data->cb->Call(3, info);
remote:              |                           ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:25:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE ODBCConnection::QuerySync(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:1341:46: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
remote:         1341 |                                 (SQLPOINTER) arraySize, 0);
remote:              |                                              ^~~~~~~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCConnection::UV_AfterBeginTransaction(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:1714:36: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:         1714 |   data->cb->Call( err ? 1 : 0, argv);
remote:              |                                    ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:25:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCConnection::UV_AfterEndTransaction(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:1896:35: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:         1896 |   data->cb->Call(err ? 1 : 0, argv);
remote:              |                                   ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:25:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCConnection::UV_AfterGetInfo(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:2100:26: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:         2100 |   data->cb->Call( 2, info);
remote:              |                          ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:25:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc_connection.cpp:19:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = node::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:85:78:   required from here
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h:10886:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
remote:        10886 |                reinterpret_cast<Callback>(callback), type);
remote:              |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = Nan::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
remote:        ../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:65:61:   required from here
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h:10886:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCStatement::UV_AfterExecute(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:246:27: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          246 |     data->cb->Call(3, info);
remote:              |                           ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCStatement::UV_AfterExecuteNonQuery(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:422:63: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(v8::Local<v8::Object>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          422 |     data->cb->Call(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 2, info);
remote:              |                                                               ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1722:3: note: declared here
remote:         1722 |   Call(v8::Local<v8::Object> target
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCStatement::UV_AfterExecuteDirect(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:573:27: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          573 |     data->cb->Call(2, info);
remote:              |                           ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCStatement::UV_AfterPrepare(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:778:28: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          778 |     data->cb->Call( 2, info);
remote:              |                            ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCStatement::UV_AfterBind(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:949:28: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          949 |     data->cb->Call( 2, info);
remote:              |                            ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE ODBCStatement::SetAttrSync(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:980:84: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
remote:          980 |       valuePtr = (SQLPOINTER)(Nan::To<v8::Int32>(info[1]).ToLocalChecked()->Value());
remote:              |                                                                                    ^
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE ODBCStatement::SetAttr(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:1047:90: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
remote:         1047 |       data->valuePtr = (SQLPOINTER)(Nan::To<v8::Int32>(info[1]).ToLocalChecked()->Value());
remote:              |                                                                                          ^
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCStatement::UV_AfterSetAttr(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:1121:28: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:         1121 |     data->cb->Call( 2, info);
remote:              |                            ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCStatement::UV_AfterClose(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:1244:24: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:         1244 |  data->cb->Call(1, info);
remote:              |                        ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_statement.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:        ../src/odbc_result.cpp:287:27: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          287 |     data->cb->Call(2, info);
remote:              |                           ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_result.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_result.cpp:312:27: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          312 |     data->cb->Call(2, info);
remote:              |                           ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_result.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:         1744 |   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
remote:              |   ^~~~
remote:        ../src/odbc_result.cpp: In static member function ‘static void ODBCResult::UV_AfterFetchAll(uv_work_t*, int)’:
remote:        ../src/odbc_result.cpp:598:27: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:          598 |     data->cb->Call(3, info);
remote:              |                           ^
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc.h:23,
remote:                         from ../src/odbc_result.cpp:24:
remote:        ../../nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
remote:        In file included from ../src/odbc_result.cpp:18:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = node::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:85:78:   required from here
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h:10886:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
remote:        10886 |                reinterpret_cast<Callback>(callback), type);
remote:              |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = Nan::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
remote:        ../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:65:61:   required from here
remote:        /app/.cache/node-gyp/14.18.1/include/node/v8.h:10886:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
remote:        /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb2
remote:        collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
remote:        make: *** [odbc_bindings.target.mk:150: Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings.node] Error 1
remote:        gyp ERR! build error 
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_ca1696e7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1097-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_ca1696e7/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_ca1696e7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build" "--IS_DOWNLOADED=true" "--IBM_DB_HOME=/tmp/build_ca1696e7/node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_ca1696e7/node_modules/ibm_db
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok 
remote:        
remote:            at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
remote:            at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
remote:            at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
remote:            at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
remote:            at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
remote:            at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:686:12) {
remote:          killed: false,
remote:          code: 1,
remote:          signal: null,
remote:          cmd: 'node-gyp configure build  --IS_DOWNLOADED=true --IBM_DB_HOME="$IBM_DB_HOME"'
remote:        }
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! ibm_db@2.8.0 install: `node installer/driverInstall.js`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the ibm_db@2.8.0 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.KQGAk/_logs/2021-11-13T21_27_43_927Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

this is an issuse i've never had before. It seems though from reading these utterly confusing logs that it is an ODBC driver issue? So i tried to reinstall `ibm_db`, as well as redo an `npm install`, but nothing changes.

has anyone had this issue before, or have any recommendations? thanks.

Comment: Add what you have configured. What manifest / config files? The Db2 Node.js driver is based on Db2 CLI (ODBC). The install should automatically download the CLI driver and install it.

Comment: Is your `node_modules/` folder tracked or ignored?

Comment: @Chris you are right, i had to ignore the node modules folder. something with the cache was causing the issue